# Wordpress & child themes - strategies to find out which .php to override?

Tags: wordpress, customization

Starting with some basic Wordpress Bootstrap Themes I'd like to modify the width for Posts and Post links.  This is more get-to-know-WP than heavy duty theme creation - I am mostly interested in how to apply minor customizations like this across different themes.  I know each theme can kinda pick which PHP files it wants to provide, so I know what works in Theme A won't necessarily work in Theme B.

I've already done this once for one theme, but now the other theme doesn't have the same PHP file names.

For example, I know that to make the widget area narrower for posts, I want to override **sidebar.php**:

```
<!-- <div id="secondary" class="widget-area col-md-4" role="complementary"> -->
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area col-lg-2" role="complementary">
```

And modifying **index.php** makes the left-side wider:

```
<!--    <section id="primary" class="content-area col-md-8"> -->
<section id="primary" class="content-area col-lg-10">
<div class="tmarker">index.php</div>  <!-- I added this! -->
```

This works fine when I am at the root of my site, as **index.php** is getting used.

However, when I navigate to a Post, I am back to:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area col-md-8">
```

and my post area hasn't expanded.  This makes sense - **index.php** isn't used here.

**How do I know which PHP file is getting composed into that post detail view so that I can override it?**

I've tried looking for 'index.php' in the page source, but I only saw the one I added myself on my child override.

I guess I could just look at all the PHPs in the editor and find all the `class="content-area col-md-8"` and trial and error them till I hit the right one.  Not much fun.  Are there better ways?

Could I at least dump all of those PHPs to files and grep for `col-md-8`?  I'd need a text export for themes.

P.S. I know Wordpress child customizations are best done in **style.css** and **functions.php**, but unless I missed something, with Bootstrap, I think I really need to hit those `class` assignments for Bootstrap to do the work instead.

Comment: A quick-and-dirty way: Most decent themes add a class to the `body` element that reflects which theme template is being used.  If you inspect the `body` element, you should be able to see which template is being used.  If your theme breaks down further than simple template levels, then you'll have to start examining the code in the given template(s) to figure out which code is running, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of tips and strategies, but one that is a "A quick-and-dirty way":

Most decent themes add a class to the body element that reflects which theme template is being used. If you inspect the body element, you should be able to see which template is being used (for example `page-template-default`, etc).

If your theme breaks down further than simple template levels, then you'll have to start examining the code in the given template(s) to figure out which code is running, etc.

Comment: Awesome.  I found `<body class="post-template-default single single-post`.  Working from your suggestion and looking for `single`, I found `single.php` and some marker text directly on the Theme's PHP showed up on the page.  Customized `single.php` for real in the child with `col-lg-10` and voila!  Probably a good way to gauge if a theme developer is following best practices too, this one was.  Txs.

Answer (score 2):

The question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10537/get-name-of-the-current-template-file) addresses something similar.

You can store the template name into a global variable and echo it into the footer.  This should tell you what template file is being loaded (`index.php`, `page.php`, etc).

The code below should be added to `functions.php`.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'var_template_include', 1000 );
function var_template_include( $t ){
    $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'] = basename($t);
    return $t;
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'get_current_template' );
function get_current_template() {
    if( !isset( $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'] ) )
        return false;

    echo $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'];
}
```